# bootstrap pills - how to display the pills tab without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav-pills

I have a [bootstrap 3 pills](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#pills) display.

It comprises of three tabs of different lengths (height).

I have inserted some code that allows a link to be clicked and a particular pill to be activated and displayed.

The links to activate the different pills are located at the bottom of the pills / tabs.

When I click the link and the pill is activated, its related tab is displayed, which is what I am wanting to achieve.

However, the screen navigates up to the top of the pill / tab automatically.

Is there a way to prevent the screen navigating to the top of the pill / tab when the link is clicked (the pill is activated)?

Here is the code I have that allows the pill / tab to be activated and displayed from a link on the page:

```
  $('[href="#publish_menu1"]').bind('click', function(event) {
    // show the 1st details pill when the link is clicked.
    $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(1) a').tab('show');
  });

  $('[href="#publish_menu2"]').bind('click', function(event) {
    // show the 3rd details pill when the link is clicked.
    $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show');
  });

  $('[href="#resume_publish_menu3"]').bind('click', function(event) {
    // show the 3rd details pill when the link is clicked.
    $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show');
  });
```

Comment: can you please post complete page code?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to grasp exactly what you are trying to achieve without the full code, but from the code you've posted, it looks like your anchors may be pointing to your divs.

```
$('[href="#resume_publish_menu3"]').bind('click', function(event) {
    // show the 3rd details pill when the link is clicked.
    $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show');
  });
```

If the href points to a div or element with the id='#resume_publish_menu3', it's going to scroll the page to the top of that div or element.

This would cause the behavior of snapping to the top of the page because if your anchors use local id's.

```
href='#home' //takes me to the div with id='home'
href='/home' //takes me to the home page within the path
```

My suggestion would be to look at what your href's are pointing to, because that might be the issue.